# How to display text in standard html

Tags: html, css, .net, asp.net-mvc

Work on asp.net MVC, One of external service return text as like following how to display this text with the standard format.

**service output.**

[image]

**Want to display above text following HTML format.**

[image]

Comment: Do we mean manipulate the text to beautify it (remove whitespaces,...) by display-as-html?

Comment: @ Ashokan Sivapragasam, yes you are right. Is it possible to beautify text to HTML?

Comment: I think you need to add html encoding for the text output

Comment: @  Rahul Swamynathan, Already try the following syntax, but it does not work for me.  @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(questionnaireElement.Text))

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Description)
```